# significantly short term log out of the control panel

Tags: logout

I am a super admin in a new EE6 install. The system has been logging me out every 5 minutes literally. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Seems to happen a lot on refresh as I'm checking my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check your settings - go to the Control Panel and have a look at the Settings and see if the **URL and Path Settings** are correct.  Then go to the Security & Privacy settings (near bottom of list on LHS)and see what **CP Session type** settings you have - change these to **Cookies Only** and check to see if the **Cookie Settings / Domain** setting has anything set - if it does clear the field.  See if those changes make a difference.

HTH

Comment: Thank you @jcogsDesign!! I have made these changes to setting and it seems pretty stable for a couple of days now. This should be marked as answered now!

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I use Chrome With dev tools open AND mobile view

Comment: Thx @benoit L I should have clarified, this happens in other inspect environment including Firefox